# Cannot access a method using Reflection API

Tags: java, reflection, jooq

I'm trying to access a setter and change the value at run-time, using reflection API. I have a `JasperReport` object which has a method named `getDefaultStyle`, which in turn allows me to call `setFontName` method, like this

```
jasperReport.getDefaultStyle().setFontName()
```

'setFontName' takes a String as method argument and sets that as font. I'm trying to change the font value during the rutime like this

```
on(jasperReport).call("getDefaultStyle").call("setFontName").set("fontName", "Helvetica");
```

But, I'm getting this error

```
org.jooq.tools.reflect.ReflectException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No similar method setFontName with params [] could be found on type class java.lang.Object.
```

Not so experienced in reflection API, could use some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know this reflection API but it seems that you transform 
`on(jasperReport).call("getDefaultStyle").call("setFontName").set("fontName", "Helvetica");`
to this:
`on(jasperReport).call("getDefaultStyle").call("setFontName", "Helvetica");`
because you need to pass the new value as argument.
Translated to "normal" java it would be  `jasperReport.getDefaultStyle().setFontName("Helvetica")`
instead of
`jasperReport.getDefaultStyle().setFontName().fontName = "Helvetica"`
I think you see that that doesn't make sense, because you first set the field with the setter() without argument and then try to set the field on the returned void

Comment: for some reasons unknown, still throwing the same exception.

Comment: @RoshanUpreti: This answer is correct, according to the publicly available Javadoc: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/base/JRBaseReport.html#getDefaultStyle-- and http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRStyle.html#setFontName-java.lang.String-. Perhaps, you need to provide a more complete example that helps better reproduce the problem, including: 1) Show how you create the `jasperReport` object, 2) Indicate the library versions of JasperReports and jOOR, etc.